# How to hold div element height 100 %, when content is changed and scrollable

Tags: html, css

The questions looks simple, but am stuck with it.I have main .`container with width: 90%; height: 100%; background-color: white`.It must be always 100 % height of the page height.My problem, when I get more content and I need to scroll down the page my, `.container` is ended.

[image]

Comment: You obviously don't want a height, but a `min-height`. Using percentages for this is tricky to get working correctly, especially if the rest of the page needs to be able to scroll normally - so I recommend you use the `vh` unit instead, `min-height: 100vh`. Go check caniuse.com for browser support, and see if that is enough for you, or if you need a fallback solution/workaround.

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because the content(child elements) is overflowing the parent element height use `overflow: scroll`

Comment: But then I will have  one more  scroll button for my container?

Comment: if you want the content not to overflow the parent then you should avoid setting height of children inside the container with pixels and use height:100% on child elements as well

Comment: Here is my settings  html,
`body {
    height: 100%; 
    max-height: 100%; 
    background-color:#FAF8F1;
}
.container{
width: 90%;
height: 100%; 
max-height: 100%; 
display:block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 background-color: white;
 padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
 border-radius: 5px; 
 border-style:ridge;
  border-width:2px; 
}`

Comment: yes but this is not happening because of the container div or body , this is happening because of the content inside your div container , like this table showing in the picture you've posted

Comment: Ok so i must all divs , inside my `.container` change height to 100 %

Comment: I've changed `#projectResults`  where is my table,   height   to `100 %` and now in `Chrome` it works correctly, but in `Mozilla` problem still here.

Answer (score 0):

There is something about height: that you might find super annoying, and that is is it is based on the % of width. so if you write height: 100%; it is actually using the width of the screen not the height. so if you want the height to scale you might want to use em units.

Comment: Source? As far as i know, the height in percentage refers to the parent's height, and defaults to 'auto' if it isn't defined:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31728022/why-is-percentage-height-not-working-on-my-div/31728799#31728799

Comment: I was a little off but here is the info. http://www.impressivewebs.com/vertical-percentages-css/

Comment: "A percentage value on height is relative to the height of the containing block", I think you were referrin to percentage in padding/margin